# Changing both PK and FK column type using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to change a bunch of PK column types, and use MySQL's Workbench to design my database.

Is it possible to change the PK's type in a given table, and have all the FK types automatically change?

Comment: If you're using Workbench, it may script it out for you. You're better off explicitly writing out the SQL for it.

Comment: @Kermit  Why not create an ERD and have the script automatically created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I performed to check the **workbench**. I created the table **employees** and **employees_hobbies**. The `PK` of table`employees` is `id_employees` the type `INT(11)`. The `employees_hobbies` table has a `FK` `id_employees` the type `INT(11)`. I tried to change the type of the field in `id_employees` of table `employees` for `CHAR(5)` and the error is as follows:

> ERROR 1025: Error on rename of './teste/#sql-4aa_10875' to
>   './teste/employees' (errno: 150) SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE
>   `teste`.`employees`  CHANGE COLUMN `id_employees` `id_employees`
>   CHAR(5) NOT NULL
>
> ERROR: Error when running failback script.

**The error means (errno: 150)**

> MySQL error code 150: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

**My tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id_employees` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employees`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `employees_hobbies` (
  `id_employees_hobbies` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_employees` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_hobbies` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employees_hobbies`),
  KEY `fk_employees_hobbies_1_idx` (`id_employees`),
  KEY `fk_employees_hobbies_2_idx` (`id_hobbies`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_hobbies_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_employees`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id_employees`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_hobbies_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_hobbies`) REFERENCES `hobbies` (`id_hobbies`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

You can not do this in Workbench.

The solution is to generate the script and parse all `FK` performing the exchange type.